# hostapd on Raspberry Pi 4 only starts when fan is connected

Tags: linux, boot, kali-linux, fan, hostapd

I run Kali on a Raspberry Pi 4 8gb. I run [hostapd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hostapd) and [dnsmasq](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dnsmasq) on boot to start an access point. This works if the small fan is connected to the Raspberry Pi. But if I reboot with the fan disconnected I get the following error from `systemctl status hostapd`:

`Failed to start access point and authentication server for wifi and ethernet`

Again, it works perfectly when the fan is connected, but how can that be? And how can it be fixed?